# STA error when opening WPF window from Winform window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

App.xaml is the startup point for the application (build action is ApplicationDefinition). This opens a WinForm window, that eventually opens a WPF window (when a menu item is clicked). At this point, the application crashes, by the WPF window constructor, with

```
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

I have tried using a Main method as the startup point with `[STAThread]` (and setting the build action of App.xaml to Page), but it didn't help. App.ApplicationStartup has `[STAThread]`. Note that the project used to be just WinForms, and WPF was added later.

Does anyone know of a possible solution? Hopefully that does not involve creating additional threads.

Thanks

Here is the call stack:

```
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()
at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()
at System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor()
at System.Windows.Window..ctor()
at MyApp.WPF.Views.Windows.Properties.ContentAdminWindow..ctor() in c:\Develop\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\WPF\Views\Windows\Properties\ContentAdminWindow.xaml.cs:line 21
at MyApp.MainForm.mainToolbarsManager_ToolClick(Object sender, ToolClickEventArgs e) in c:\Develop\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\MainForm.cs:line 867
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager.OnToolClick(ToolClickEventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager.FireEvent(ToolbarEventIds id, EventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolBase.OnToolClick()
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolMenuItem.OnClick()
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.PopupMenuItemUIElement.DoClickProcessing(MouseEventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.PopupMenuItemUIElement.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.UIElement.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.TextUIElementBase.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.ProcessMouseUpHelper(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.ProcessMouseUp(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.Utilities.ProcessEvent(Control control, ProcessEvent eventToProcess, EventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.PopupControlBase.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
at MyApp.Program.LogonFormEventListener.TestEventRaised(Logon o, EventArgs e) in c:\Develop\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\Program.cs:line 56
at MyApp.Logon.OKbutton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Develop\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\Logon.cs:line 40
at Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButtonBase.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButtonBase.PerformClick()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
at MyApp.WPF.App.ApplicationStartup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in c:\Develop\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\WPF\App.xaml.cs:line 35
at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at MyApp.WPF.App.Main() in c:\Develop\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Debug\WPF\App.g.cs:line 0
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Here is the Main method in obj\Debug\WPF\app.g.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Application Entry Point.
/// </summary>
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
public static void Main() {
    MyApp.WPF.App app = new MyApp.WPF.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

Comment: Are you opening WPF window from background thread?

Comment: @RohitVats no - plain old `new myWPFWindow().ShowDialog()` in the code behind for the menu click

Comment: Putting [STAThread] on the ApplicationStartup event handler certainly isn't going to work.  Something is unguessably wrong with the way your program gets started.  You need to post the content of the Call Stack window so we can see.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks - attached is the call stack

Comment: It is the normal auto-generated app.g.cs file.  Except that the path is weird, it is normally in the obj\Debug directory.  Hard to guess why it has "WPF" in the pathname.  Have a look at the file, find the Main() method.

Comment: @HansPassant I appended the Main method to my question

Comment: No, that definitely has the [STAThread] attribute.  No idea why you are having this problem.  Whenever I see Infragistics in a call stack I do an Application.Run().  Good luck with it.